# Have password automatically entered when ssh

Tags: ssh

From my laptop, I often ssh into another machine in my university department. I have to put in a password every time currently.

Could someone give me an idiot's guide to having the password be automatically entered each time I log in please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use authentication keys instead of passwords to login with SSH. Here is a little tutorial on how to do that : http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Comment: ssh keygen is your friend http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override by enabling Password less authentication. But you should install keys (pub, priv) before going for that.

Execute the following commands at local server.

```
Local $> ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Press ENTER for all options prompetd. No values need to be typed.

```
Local $> cd .ssh
Local $> scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@targetmachine:
Prompts for pwd$>  ENTERPASSWORD
```

Connect to remote server using the following command

```
Local $> ssh user@targetmachine
Prompts for pwd$> ENTERPASSWORD
```

Execute the following commands at remote server

```
Remote $> mkdir .ssh
Remote $> chmod 700 .ssh
Remote $> cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
Remote $> chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
Remote $> exit
```

Execute the following command at local server to test password-less authentication.
It should be connected without password.

```
$> ssh user@targetmachine
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Linux. Lot of places in the internet where it is already documented.

For example(s):

http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 2):

You can log in without providing password if PKI (public key infrastructure) is set up.

Otherwise you'll have to look for ssh client that can store passwords and supports your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool (such as AutoHotkey, assuming you are using Windows) to record and replay key sequences: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: -1 This is crazy insecure. Use an ssh agent for this.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: The question itself is insecure.

Comment: Not really. You can use an SSH agent to safely keep pass phrases in memory to log into remote system without being asked for a password and without having to store the password in an unsafe place.